curl metrics variables and dimensions
Hi and thanks for your help.
I try to pass pair of arguments in a curl command.
I already found out how to pass single variables, like my MetricType, MetricName, current time and the value from $1.
I can pass both the Dim1Name AND the value, like this:
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json"
--header "X-SF-TOKEN: ${TOKEN}" -X POST -i https://URL/datapoint
--data '{"'"${MetricType}"'": [{ "metric": "'"${MetricName}"'","value": 300,

    "dimensions": {"'"${Dim1Name}"'": "'"${Dim1Value}"'"}

    }]}'

What I'd like to achieve is something like this, where DimOption=Dim1Name: Dim1Value so the code would look like this (but the Name and Value need quotes).
Is it possible ? (And with a coma as well in case I want to send 2+ pairs of arguments)
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json"
--header "X-SF-TOKEN: ${TOKEN}" -X POST -i https://URL/datapoint
--data '{"'"${MetricType}"'": [{ "metric": "'"${MetricName}"'","value": 300,

    "dimensions": {"'"${DimOption}'""}

    }]}'


Your question is good. To help future readers it would be great if you can change the title to something like: curl with dynamic body or how to send dynamic json body to curl

Multi line bash script
You can use a multi-line script for easier handling of the body and without worry about the quotes scape:
send.sh
data=$(cat data.json)

new_data=${data/@name/jane}
new_data=${new_data/@last_name/doe}

curl localhost:8080/foo -d "$new_data" -H "Content-Type: application/json"
echo

data.json
{
    "hello": "@name @last_name"
}

result

Explanation

We are reading a data.json file with the json content
Inside of data.json you can use placeholders to make it dynamic

@name
@last_name


Then using bash, we are replacing the place holders with the desired values
Finally the evaluated json string is sent to the curl

